# How to handle array response from elastic api with faraday?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, elasticsearch, faraday

I want to receive all Elastic Cloud configuration templates from the Elastic Cloud API with faraday in my Ruby on Rails application.

I've tried to workaround and modify the api call, but it's not possible to not get an array as a response.

This is the repsonse from the api:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Small Template",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Medium Template",
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "Big Template",
    "id": 3
  }
]
```

This is my faraday configuration.

```rb
Faraday.new(url: "https://#{ENV['ECE_USERNAME']}:#{ENV['ECE_PASSWORD']}@#{ENV['ECE_HOST']}") do |c|
      c.response :json, parser_options: {symbolize_names: true}
      c.response :logger
      c.use JSONParser
      c.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
end
```

And the api call:

```rb
@conn.get('/api/v1/platform/configuration/templates/deployments?stack_version').body
```

This is the error message I receive

```
undefined method `has_key?' for #<Array:xxxxx>
```

I don't want to use anything else, but faraday. I'm open to new gems to help faraday, but this client should stay.

How can I setup faraday to handle the array response or how can I workaround my problem?

Comment: What is JSONParser? I think it's not anything standard to Faraday, looking at this: https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/search?q=JSONParser&unscoped_q=JSONParser

Comment: JSONParsers is a custom class to parse the response. I removed it and now it works.

Comment: Good. I guess it assumed that received JSON is an object, not an array.

Comment: Exactly. It 'has_key?'ed a key in the root, but arrays obviously don't have keys.